# trouble using lenskit with conda

Tags: conda, lenskit

I am using lenskit to make a rec sys for the first time. I followed the lenskit [getting started](https://lkpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/GettingStarted.html) tutorial, but when I used pip there were runtime issues. I am now trying to use conda instead(as lenskit suggests), but have run into an issue. Conda cannot seem to find lenskit when running the python file
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lenskit'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D9XP.png). When I "conda list" all requirements, I verify that lenskit is installed [requirement.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enDX0.png)

Comment: It's hard to answer without more information. I am not familiar with the `py` command - I always run Python with `python`; is it possible that `py` is a different Python than the one in your Conda environment?

Comment: thank you, I tried using `python` instead of `py` and it worked. `Py` used the newest version of python and `python` used the older that I wanted to use.